# HQL select query calls object constructor but object is not in result list

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

We have a HQL SELECT query that, as a result, returns Java objects.  To our surprise, some objects are missing in the result list.

I've checked the db for one of the missing objects and could not find a problem.  Furthermore, I set a break point in the constructor of 'ParsableObject' that watches for the values of the missing object and it is triggers.  But yet, that object is not in the result list.

The result contains some other objects and there is no exception thrown.  Are there any known issues that I should look out for?

What I did not do yet: Check the logs of hibernate. I've set `hibernate.show_sql` to true but did not get a log.  But that's a different issue.

The prepared query:

```
<query name="ObjectDAOHibernate.getSessionObjects">
    <query-param name="idSession" type="long"/>
    <![CDATA[ 
    select new de.smartshift.ucchecker.model.ParsableObject(
        to.idObject, to.objectName, to.description,
        tom.codeSize, tom.codeSizeModified,
        tom.lineCount, tom.normalizedLineCount, tom.commentLineCount, tom.lineCountModified,
        tot.objectTypeCode,
        ocst.idObjectState,
        odst.idObjectState,
        opst.idObjectState,
        otst.idObjectState,
        oust.idObjectState,
        sapr3data.devClass,
        to.standard,
        to.tblFolder.relevant) 
    from 
        de.smartshift.ucchecker.db.hib.TblObject to join to.tblFolder tf 
                    join tf.tblSession ts                     
                    join to.tblObjectType tot
                    join to.tblObjectMetadata tom
                    join to.tblObjectProcessingState tops
                    join tops.tblObjectStateByRefidCustomerState ocst
                    join tops.tblObjectStateByRefidDownloadState odst
                    join tops.tblObjectStateByRefidParserState opst
                    join tops.tblObjectStateByRefidToolState     otst
                    join tops.tblObjectStateByRefidUploadState oust
                    join to.tblSapr3Data sapr3data
   where
       ts.idSession=:idSession
   order by
       to.objectName ASC, tot.objectTypeCode ASC
   ]]>
```

Comment: Your missing object may be missing a corresponding row in one of the associated tables.  Since your joins appear to be all inner-joins only those that actually have a corresponding row in every one of those tables should be returned.

Comment: There are several possible sources of the problem - your HQL is wrong, the SQL generated by Hibernate is wrong, your data is wrong, your result expectation is wrong. You provided just the HQL, but you didn't write what it should do. So it's just about guessing.

Comment: @Ján Halasa. As the constructor of ParsableObject is called with all the fields of the object that I'm missing, I assume that the SQL query somehow succeeded and yielded the expected result. So, the question is: Why is the object created but not in the result list?

Comment: @vsfDawg. That was my first idea and I checked the db: all rows are present. And: the constructor is called with the correct values, so no problem here

Comment: If you can debug it, check at which point Hibernate creates the object with the data you are missing and follow it to see why the object doesn't end up in the result list. Often it's enough to read the method names to get the idea what part of Hibernate processing you are in.